# Microsoft SQL Server : check constraint with generated name

Tags: sql-server, constraints, unique, tempdb

In T-SQL, it's normally best to name all constraints you create, including check constraints.

```
alter table mytable with check 
    add constraint myconstraint check (mycol > 0)
```

If you don't provide an explicit name (`myconstraint`), then the server will generate a unique name for you, which isn't particularly readable in error messages.

Or so everyone says. But is it even possible to get this generated name for check constraints? I have seen it for foreign key constraints and unique constraints, but I don't know how to create a check constraint without specifying the name.

If I leave out the name `myconstraint` in the above T-SQL, it's a syntax error.

The reason I ask is for check constraints in tempdb. The names of temporary tables are per-session, so it's no problem to call your table `#x`. You can have that name in several different programs (or several instances of the same program running concurrently) and they don't clash. Only the global temporary tables (as `##x`) need to have globally unique names.

However, constraint names have to be unique within tempdb and are not per-session. So if you give them a readable name, you run the risk of clashing with the same name in other connections. You need to do something to make it globally unique, either pasting in some gunk on the client side or resorting to dynamic SQL. I would greatly prefer to leave the name unspecified and have the server handle the job of naming the constraint, as already happens when I create unique indexes on my temporary tables.

How can I make a check constraint without specifying a name for it?

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU15-GDR) (KB4583461) - 13.0.5865.1 (X64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your syntax is wrong (you didn't show us). Simply

```
ALTER TABLE elbat
            WITH CHECK
            ADD CHECK (nmuloc = 1);
```

should work fine and SQL Server will generate a name.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  If you remove just the word `myconstraint` it's a syntax error, but remove `constraint myconstraint` and it works.

Answer (score 2):

When you explicitly create a `CONSTRAINT` then you *must* specify a name. It is when you are creating a `CONSTRAINT` implicitly that you get one with an automatic name.

Take the following DDL statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                          SomeDate date DEFAULT GETDATE(),
                          SomeInt int DEFAULT 1 CHECK (SomeInt> 0));
```

The above creates a table, with 3 columns, but also with **four** `CONSTRAINT`s. These constraints are:

- A Primary key constraint on `ID`
- A default constraint on `SomeDate`
- A default constraint on `SomeInt`,
- A Check constraint on `SomeInt`.

We can validate this by looking at the `sys` objects:

```sql
SELECT N'Key Constraint', [name] AS ConstraintName
FROM sys.key_constraints kc
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable')
UNION ALL
SELECT N'Default Constraint', [name] AS ConstraintName
FROM sys.default_constraints 
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable')
UNION ALL
SELECT N'Check Constraint', [name] AS ConstraintName
FROM sys.check_constraints
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable');
```

When I ran this, this generated the generated names were:

| Constraint Type | Constraint Name |
| --- | --- |
| Key Constraint | PK__MyTable__3214EC27B4E6D2B3 |
| Default Constraint | DF__MyTable__SomeDat__6A33284E |
| Check Constraint | CK__MyTable__SomeInt__6B274C87 |

---

That doesn't mean you can't explicitly provide a name when creating the `CONSTRAINT` within the DDL of the table though. If you want to define them as part of the column it would look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.OtherTable (ID int IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_OtherTable PRIMARY KEY,
                             SomeDate date CONSTRAINT DF_OtherTable_SomeDate DEFAULT GETDATE(),
                             SomeInt int CONSTRAINT DF_OtherTable_SomeInt DEFAULT 1
                                         CONSTRAINT chk_OtherTable_SomeInt CHECK (SomeInt> 0));
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by explicit and implicit.  The answer from sticky bit shows how to explicitly create a constraint with an automatic name.  It doesn't have to be done as part of the `create table`.

Comment: `CREATE CONSTRAINT`... You are **explicitly** creating a `CONSTRAINT`, @EdAvis .

Comment: Right, so I don't understand what you say "when you explicitly create a constraint you must specify a name".  Since the other answer shows how to explicitly create one and not specify the name.

Comment: @EdAvis - when you specify the `CONSTRAINT` key word you must also specify a name

Comment: As Martin said, when you add the `CONSTRAINT` key word, you are being *explicit* about what you are creating;  At that point you have to therefore define the name. If you omit the `CONSTRAINT` keyword (which I am therefore saying you are implicitly creating it, rather than being explicit it's a `CONSTRAINT`) you *don't* need the name. Apologies if my terminology was ambiguous, @EdAvis .

Comment: OK thanks, you mean the important point is whether you have `constraint`, not whether you are making it as part of `create table` or `alter table`.

Comment: Correct, @EdAvis . This is why I mentioned being explicit about making a `CONSTRAINT`. In the first example you can see that I omit `CONSTRAINT` in all cases, and so all them `CONSTRAINT`s created have automatically generated named. On the other hand, in the latter example they all explicitly state `CONSTRAINT`, which therefore **must** be followed by the name of said `CONSTRAINT`.